# Find first uncommented line in vim without erasing search

Tags: vim, vim-registers, nerdcommenter

When uncommenting code in vim, I want to have a macro to jump to the first uncommented line in a variety of files. I am using the nerdcommenter in Vim so (after highlighting the first commented line) I search for any line starting with any non `#` or `%`, but still containing some non-whitespace character with:

```
/^\s*\(#\|%\)\@!\S
```

But search replaces my search buffer. Can I do such a search without erasing my search buffer?

I see no such functionality in the nerdcommenter documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the last search to a variable like so:

```
let orig_search = @/
```

Then after you do the search, you can do this:

```
let @/ = orig_search
```